# What are the adjacency bonuses in xcom?

Tags: xcom-enemy-within

I know cyberlabs and foundry has adjacency with workshop

I know gene labs has adjacency with lab

What about others?

I know power sources and satelite uplinks have with one another.

Any others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [XCOM Wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/XCOM_headquarters#Generators) :

**Generators**
+2 Power for every adjacent power facility.

**Uplinks**
+1 satellite capacity for every two adjacent uplinks.

**Research**
Laboratory, Genetics Lab : +10% increase to research speed for every adjacent laboratory.
Alien Containment : none.

**Engineering**
Workshop, Foundry, Cybernetics Lab : +10% on resources used when building vehicles.

Comment: so only gene labs and other laboratories have adjacency bonus with other laboratory.

Comment: @Sharen Correct.